# Settings a FormsAuthentication Cookie for another application

Tags: c#, .net, forms-authentication, session-cookies

I have two .NET 4.5 MVC (C#) applications running on the same hostname, one in the root of the domain (public/members only site), the other in a subfoler (admin site).  Both use forms authentication, with different cookie names (so you can be logged in to admin and members site at the same time)

I would like to be able to, from the admin site, set the cookie for the member's site, and then redirect there, allowing an Administrator to "Login As" the member.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've posted some code that shows how to create and set the FormsAuthentication cookie manually. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614965/asp-net-where-can-i-find-a-fast-custom-membership-provider/2616232#2616232 for details.

Comment: Thank you Morten.  That should do it!